# Open Delta's "virtual" power factor

Tags: transformer, power-factor-correction, delta

Open Delta yields 57% of power instead of the 86% it would yield if no 30-degree angle gets in the way. Can that 30-degree angle be corrected with a capacitor and an inductor (it requires a cap in one phase and an inductor in the other phase)?? (it behaves like a power factor which is not caused by a load -- assume a resistive load).

This is a common question for those using power transmission systems.  The two part question is: 1. Why can't an open delta with deliver two-thirds of the power of a balanced delta, if the loads are the same on the two remaining windings?  and 2. Can this power be achieved by the addition of reactive components?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? This seems like an interesting question, but I don't understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yep, a schematic or a reference would be helpful!

Comment: This question seems clear and understandable.